# html input range thumb smooth movement

Tags: html, css, forms, input

I have an HTML input range set up with a bunch of CSS changes to the appearance, and I was wondering if there was any way to make it smoothly change from wherever it is to where the user changes?

```css
input[type=range] {
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        width: 100%;
        height: 20px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        border: 1px solid;
        background: none;
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px #555, 0px 0px 25px 0px #555 inset;
        transition: 0.4s all ease-out;
        outline: none;
    }

    input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        width: 30px;
        height: 30px;
        background-color: #CCC;
        border: solid 1px #333;
        border-radius: 4px;
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px #555, 0px 0px 25px 0px #555 inset;
        cursor: pointer;
        transition: 0.4s all ease-out;
    }

    input[type=range]:hover {
        background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 13px 0px #444, 0px 0px 20px 0px #444 inset;
    }

    input[type=range]:hover::-webkit-slider-thumb {
        border: solid 1px #444;
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 0px #444, 0px 0px 20px 0px #444 inset;
    }

    input[type=range]:focus {
        background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 18px 0px #333, 0px 0px 15px 0px #333 inset;
    }

    input[type=range]:focus::-webkit-slider-thumb {
        border: solid 1px #333;
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 22px 0px #333, 0px 0px 15px 0px #333 inset;
    }
```

```html
<input type="range" id="brightness_slider" value="90" step="1" min="30" max="100">
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These are the things that affect the smoothness:

1. The width of the banner
2. The min/max range
3. The size of steps

So if you have:

1. 1000px wide range input
2. 0 - 1000 range
3. Step size of 1

Each step will be just 1px, and it will be quite smooth.

If you have:

1. 1000px wide range input
2. 0 -100 range
3. Step size of 25

It will snap between the allowable values, appearing less fluid.

This is really a feature of the interaction between your step size and your range, and provides useful feedback to the user on what values are acceptable.

Comment: How can we add a transition so that when it moves to the next step, it does so smoothly rather than instantaneously.

Answer (score 2):

I realize this is quite old at this point but the solution I came up with I found was pretty elegant and easy to do so I thought I would share it.

First I had an indexed scroller to make it easier. For example, I had an array of values like the following:

myArray = [0, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000]

I set my input range min to 0, max to the number of items in the array 4. Then I set the step to .01 to get smooth scrolling.

On the input event I did the following:

```
index = Math.round(event * 1);
value = myArray[index];
```

And that's basically it, as you scroll it will be smooth, and the values will change in between the ranges as you would expect.