# JavaScript: drag range input with pure JS

Tags: javascript

I was wondering if this was possible. As a user I can click on a range slider and it changes, I can detect range events, I can change the `value` property of the slider. But can I programatically change a slider by simulating some form of dragging on the element?

I've tried a couple of approaches that relied on programmatically creating JS events and so far no luck. It is not being dragged.

Approach 1:

- click on element,
- focus element,
- use arrow keys

Approach 2:

- determine absolute position in window of element
- click

Is it possible?

Comment: Related?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40441445/html-input-range-thumb-smooth-movement

Comment: It seems not at all related. One way to think about this question is "how would you use the mouse programatically to drag a slider?" Obviously, we cannot use the mouse pointer in a browser, but I want to get as close to that ideal as possible by only using JS/HTML/CSS inside a browser. So I want to create programmatic events that make sure the range slider is dragged. I don't want to set the `value` property of the slider directly as I want the dragged slider event to actually happen on the HTML element itself. That's the goal, I want to know if that's possible.